# grails v3, where did platform-core go - i want to use menus in form

Tags: grails, plugins, navigation

just starting a grails v3 project and had an immediate problem ....

I did grails list-plugins but cant see platform-core plugin -

when I try and add to gradle.build it cant resolve the plugin in intellij when you refresh the project.  Where has navigations API gone to ?

listing:

- airbrake-grails
- ajax-tags
- ajaxdependancyselection
- asset-pipeline
- audit-logging
- aws-sdk
- boselecta
- build-test-data
- cache
- cache-ehcache
- cache-headers
- cassandra
- clojure
- csv
- database-migration
- db-reverse-engineer
- enforcer
- export
- facebook-sdk
- feature-switch
- feeds
- fields
- geb
- gorm-envers
- grails-asset-pipeline
- grails-cache
- grails-cascade-validation
- grails-console
- grails-cxf
- grails-cxf-client
- grails-filterpane
- grails-google-visualization
- grails-hibernate-filter
- grails-http-builder-helper
- grails-jesque
- grails-json-apis
- grails-markdown
- grails-quartz
- grails-redis
- grails-spring-websocket
- grails-wschat-plugin
- greenmail
- grooscript
- gscripting
- hibernate
- http-builder-helper
- jasypt-encryption
- jenjir
- jms
- joda-time
- jsbdemo
- json-annotations-marshaller
- jssh
- ldap-server
- log-hibernate-stats
- mail
- mongodb
- newrelic
- oauth
- quartz
- quartz-monitor
- rateable
- recaptcha
- redis-gorm
- rendering
- request-tracelog
- scaffolding
- segment
- sentry
- simple-spring-security
- spring-security-acl
- spring-security-appinfo
- spring-security-cas
- spring-security-core
- spring-security-kerberos
- spring-security-ldap
- spring-security-rest
- spring-security-shiro
- spring-security-ui
- taggable
- views-gradle
- views-json
- views-markup
- wkhtmltopdf
- wschat

Comment: platform-core was not migrated to grails 3 and from what I heard, there are no plans to do that because it was abandoned

Comment: Thanks - i'd not heard that at all - if it was abandoned, and the navigation plugin hasnt been ported and you want to use menu bars, are we back to coding this stuff by hand/creating a new plugin to try and do this?  I'm trying to do some simplish stuff - but was looking to avoid spending alot of time going over basics - either that or i can drop back and use v2 i guess and get all the plugins that do exist for 2 - even though its end of the line so to speak

Comment: You could try to migrate or just use part of platform-core which you need in your own plugin/app. Or switch to newer approach like SPA, Grails 3 has really nice support for Angular already